# How can I record exercise submission in a learnr R tutorial?

Tags: r

I wrote a series of learnr tutorials to help students learn R, and I need to record when students have submitted an answer to a question or an exercise.  A section of the `learnr` documentation touches on this topic (https://rstudio.github.io/learnr/publishing.html#recording_events), but not at the level of detail I need, apparently.  I have two main question areas, and below those I've pasted code for a sample tutorial.

1. Setting the `tutorial.event_recorder` option:  The `learnr` documentation states

   > "You can capture events by using a custom event recorder function. This function is specified via the `tutorial.event_recorder` global option."

   I found one example online where this is defined in the setup chunk as

   ```
   options(tutorial.event_recorder = learnr:::debug_event_recorder)
   ```

   So that's what I've put in my code, but are there other possible options?  Am I even using it correctly?
2. Actually recording events:  the `learnr` documentation creates an example event recorder function printing to stdout as

   ```
   tutorial_event_recorder <- function(tutorial_id, tutorial_version,
                                       user_id, event, data) {
   cat(tutorial_id, " (", tutorial_version, "): ", user_id , "\n", sep = "")
   cat("event: ", event, "\n", sep = "")
   }
   ```

Let's say I was happy with that level of event recording:  I'm assuming I define it in some R code chunk, but where do I call it?  Are `tutorial_id`, `tutorial_version`, and `user_id` global arguments that are defined by the program once I set the `tutorial.event_recorder` option?  Then do I define the event as `exercise_submission`, for example?  Is there an argument that specifies which exercise or question was submitted?  I typically have several exercises and questions per tutorial.

I have pasted an example of my tutorial code if this helps.  Eventually I would like to incorporate the `checkr` package and its event recording, but I don't have time to do that well at the moment.  The tutorials are hosted on a server but I am first trying just to get event recording to work locally.  Thank you very much!

````
---
title: "Tutorial:  Categorical Variables"
output: learnr::tutorial
runtime: shiny_prerendered
tutorial:
  id: "toytorial"
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(learnr)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
tutorial_options(exercise.eval = FALSE)
options(tutorial.event_recorder = learnr:::debug_event_recorder)
```

### Test yourself

Use the `dim()` command to get the number of columns and rows in the data frame 'iris'.
```{r, ex1, exercise=TRUE, echo = FALSE}

```

```{r, q1, echo=FALSE}
question("How many rows are in the 'iris' data frame?",
  answer("5"),
  answer("150", correct=TRUE)
)
```
````

EDIT:  After Andrie's answer on 8/24 and the helpful sample tutorial Andrie posted at github.com/rstudio/learnr/issues/182 I have updated my setup chunk in my sample tutorial to:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(learnr)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)

tutorial_options(exercise.eval = FALSE)
new_recorder <- function(tutorial_id, tutorial_version, user_id, event, data) {
    cat(tutorial_id, " (", tutorial_version, "): ", user_id, ", ", event, ", ", data$label, ", ", data$answers, ", ", data$correct, "\n", sep = "")
}

options(tutorial.event_recorder = new_recorder)

```
````

Now that I know to look at the R Markdown window in RStudio I see the recording as questions are answered or exercises attempted.  I still cannot figure out how to write the event recording to a file or database:  `sink()` doesn't seem to work for me.

Comment: Did you find out how to write the event recording to a file or database?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't, but I haven't been able to look into it much since I posted this.  I am hopeful that there may be some newer tools that will help.  The submitr package, maybe?  [link](https://github.com/rstudio/learnr/issues/341)

Answer (score 1):

I ran your code, and observed the following output from `stdout` (in the `RMarkdown` pane if you're using RStudio).

This output answers your first question, about how to define the `event`.  From the output it is clear that the `learnr` recording function automatically records the event. In this case the event is `exercise_submission` and `question_submission` respectively.

```
C:/Users/apdev/Documents/temp (1.0): apdev
event: exercise_submission
List of 6
 $ label        : chr "ex1"
 $ code         : chr "\ndim(iris)\n"
 $ output       : 'html' chr "\n\n\n<pre><code>[1] 150   5</code></pre>\n"
  ..- attr(*, "html")= logi TRUE
  ..- attr(*, "html_dependencies")= list()
 $ error_message: NULL
 $ checked      : logi FALSE
 $ feedback     : NULL

C:/Users/apdev/Documents/temp (1.0): apdev
event: question_submission
List of 4
 $ label   : chr "q1"
 $ question: chr "How many rows are in the &#39;iris&#39; data frame?"
 $ answers : chr "5"
 $ correct : logi FALSE
```

Your other questions are answered in the documentation under the heading [Tutorial identifiers](https://rstudio.github.io/learnr/publishing.html#tutorial_identifiers).  In short, `learnr` will use the following defaults for the identifiers:

- `tutorial_id` : Network origin and path of tutorial.
- `tutorial_version` : 1.0
- `user_id` : Account name of server user executing the tutorial

I have tried this and it works out of the box with RStudio Connect.

---

However, I suspect there might be a bug in the `learnr` package, since it seems that changing the defaults in the YAML header doesn't have any effect.  I'm still trying to get to the bottom of this.

Comment: Update, I've opened an issue on `learnr` at https://github.com/rstudio/learnr/issues/182

Answer (score 1):

Regarding writing the event recording to a file, a basic way to do this is by passing `file = "/my_path/my_filename.txt"` and `append = TRUE` as additional arguments to the `cat` function in your `new_recorder` function.

Comment: This works perfectly, but is there any way to record the numerical input instead of TRUE and FALE for correct and incorrect answers?